# Scala play Scheduler vs Actors for background jobs

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm new to Scala and to Play framework, and I'm trying to figure out how to use background jobs.

I found that there's basically two ways to schedule a job: create an Actor, or schedule an asynchronous task.

I want to ask for an advice, what way is better when? I find Actors to be very complicated, a lot of boilerplate code, I don't like to write more code to trigger an action than the actual action code.

Here is an example of how I use scheduler.

```
def send(purchase: Purchase): Unit = 
  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(100.milliseconds) {
    execute(purchase)
  }

def execute(purchase: Purchase): Unit = {
  ... send email ...
  ... calculate stuff and write to DB ...
}
```

Comparing to the code above, if using Actors, I need first to declare an Actor:

```
object ConfiguredActor {
  case object GetConfig
}
class ConfiguredActor @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) extends Actor {
  ...
}
```

Then bind it

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[ConfiguredActor]("configured-actor")
  }
}
```

Then inject and use it

```
class Application @Inject() (@Named("configured-actor") configuredActor: ActorRef)
                            (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

  def getConfig = Action.async {
    (configuredActor ? GetConfig).mapTo[String].map { message =>
      Ok(message)
    }
  }
}
```

And there's also a concept of `child actors` that I can't understand when to use it.

The documentation doesn't explicitly say when each approach should be used. I have a feeling that Scheduler is better to use with fire-and-forget tasks, and Actors are better when the response is needed. But I'm not sure.

What are the best practices and example use cases for Scheduler and Actor?

Comment: Could you also add an example illustrating why you think actors are complicated or how you end up with a lot of boilerplate code?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, updated it!